# assigning a specific record in a ResultSet to a variable

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I want to retrieve a set of records from a database, do a rs.next() and then assign the result of this to a variable to pass to a method that will use this record, in the same way that I would without assigning it to a variable and passing it to a method
is there any way to do this?
I'm using JAVA (1.5)

---

Thank you for all the answers

I do not want to pass the whole resultSet to a method, only the current row, but as I understand, it is not possible to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to assign the result of *rs.next()* to a variable?

I'm afraid you cannot do that. You can have a reference from that rs and process it in other method ( the same way you would without assign it to a var )

When you pass the rs as an argument to a method that is exactly what you're doing already.

```
while( rs.next() ) { 
    list.add( createFrom( rs ) );
}

...

public Object createFrom( ResultSet rs ) {  // Here rs is a copy of the reference in the while above. 
}
```

Did I get right your question?

Comment: Technically, you can, it returns a bool :P

Comment: I realise now that my question was not correct, as rs.next() returns a boolean value, not the current row. 
If the resultSet is passed to a method, is it passed with the current row being the same as the row in the calling method?

Comment: Yes, it is the same! So you cannot pass the result set without the possibility the other is calling next()

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not supported out of the box, but maybe the following idea may help you:

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
while (rs.next()) {
  Map<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
    row.put(meta.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
  }
  processRow(row);
}
```

The problem is, you need to cast the values from the `row`-map in `processRow()` and it will not work for all type/driver combinations (BLOBs, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you now. :)

No, it’s not possible to do it that way. The `ResultSet` changes its internal state on each call to `ResultSet.next()` so storing the reference to it won’t get you anywhere. You have to extract the data you want into some custom object and store that.

```
CustomData cd = new CustomData();
cd.setString1(rs.getString(1));
cd.setInt1(rs.getInt(2));
...
```

You can then store the `cd` variable and get on with processing your `ResultSet`.

Answer (score -1):

I often find List> data structure very useful while working with result sets.